# Lua with nginx in openresty : pass a request to FastCGI if data does not found in redis cache

Tags: django, caching, nginx, lua, redis

I have a Django website which is running on Nginx with fcgi .
For url `/gifts/` i want to implement some logic into lua inside nginx.conf file by using openresty .

```
location /gifts {
                    try_files $uri @redis_cache;
                }


                location @redis_cache {
                        default_type text/html;
                        content_by_lua '
                                -- fetching key and values from url
                                local args = ngx.req.get_uri_args()
                                --creating redis connection
                                local redis = require "resty.redis";
                                local red = redis:new()
                                red:set_timeout(1000) -- 1 sec
                                local ok, err = red:connect("127.0.0.1", 6379)
                                if not ok then
                                        ngx.log(ngx.ERR, err, "Redis failed to connect")
                                        return ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE)
                                end
                                if not args["key"] then
                                        return ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_NOT_FOUND)

                                end
                                if args["value"] then
                                        local ok, err = red:set(args["key"], args["value"])
                                end
                                if not ok then
                                        ngx.say("Please pass key value pair to store in cache", err)
                                end
                                -- getting data from redis cache
                                local res, err = red:get(args["key"])
                                if not res then
                                        return  ngx.say("value is not in redis cache", err, "|")
                                end
                                ngx.say("Value found in Redis is: ", res)
                         ';
                }
```

Everythig is working fine as per requirement but there is one problem i want to redirect request to fcgi if cache is not available into Redis.
Please help me how to proceed with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to serve the content from fcgi, use [internal redirection](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule#ngx.exec). If you also want to fill the cache from Lua you should look at [subrequests](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule#ngx.location.capture) instead.

Comment: thanks. can you provide any example code for subrequests .thank you

Comment: Something like: `local value = ngx.location.capture("/my_fcgi_url").body; red:set(args["key"], value); return ngx.say("Value from FCGI: ", value)` Of course add error checking etc. Read the `ngx.location.capture` documentation.